# Typecast overloading

Tags: c++, casting

I could overload '+' operator but I am not sure how I could typecast for the NewType. I would like it to be typecasted to any other variable type. Can you please provide some pointers? Thanks a lot!

```
#include <iostream>

class NewType {
private:
  float val;

public:
  NewType(float v) { val = v; }
  friend NewType operator+(const NewType &c1, const NewType &c2);
  float GetVal() const { return val; }
};

NewType operator+(const NewType &c1, const NewType &c2) { return NewType(c1.val + c2.val); }

int main() {
  NewType a = 13.7;
  // Here is the problem, I would like this to print 13.
  std::cout << (int) a << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to overload `operator int` for your class.

Comment: Check e.g. [this user-defined conversions reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator).

Answer (score 2):

> I would like it to be typecasted to any other variable type.

For *any other variable type* you need a templated user-defined conversion:

```
class NewType {
public
// ...
   template<typename T>
   explicit operator T() const { return T(val); } 
// ...
};
```

`explicit` (here C++11 and up) makes sure you will use explicit cast, i.e.:

```
NewType a = 13.7;
int n = a; // compile error
int n2 = static_cast<int>(a); // now OK
```

---

You could also use uniform initialization in your user-defined conversion operator:

```
   template<typename T>
   explicit operator T() const { return T{val}; }
```

this will give you additional warning in case your cast could require narrowing. But as I see under gcc this generates only warnings by default (as I remember this is by design - due to lots of legacy code would break), under clang it generates error:

```
main.cpp:15:16: error: type 'float' cannot be narrowed to 'int' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]
      return T{val};
```

and the same Visual Studio generates error.

Comment: I am not sure its a very good idea to template the cast operator without constraints.... That would make otherwise simple errors in wrong expressions appear bogus. And it can do bad things in places you wouldn't think of....

Comment: @WhiZTiM I agree, it seems scarry - I have added `explicit` so that exlicit cast must be used